# Custom Navigation Bar in iOS 5

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, ios5

I use a class to style the NavigationControllers in iOS 5. The problem I have is the moreNavigationController which is created automatically. I found a way to style the moreNavigation itself,

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5.0){
    [self.rootController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:     [UIImage imageNamed:@"noten_header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

but i have no clue how I style the edit view of the moreNavigationController (if you are on the tab "more" and click the edit button). Any ideas except creating a new moreNavigationController?